# Static 'function' in vba/excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I just have a very simple question regarding vba.

I understand that a **static variable** in vba keeps its previous value rather then reseting it each time the function is called. However, I was wondering how could I have a "static function" rather than a variable. Let me clarify this with a simple code:

```
Function Alt(Soc1 As Double)
Static D As Integer

If Soc1 >= 40 Then
    Alt = 0
ElseIf Soc1 <= 30 Then
    Alt = 1
End If

End Function
```

Here I would like the variable-function **Alt** to keep its previous value so that I get a sort of "hysteresis" behaviour. However if I add:

```
Static Alt As Integer
```

I get an error when calling the function Alt().

Also if I add a line such as:`Alt = D` while D is decalred as static I get an alternating value of Alt (1,0,1,0,1,0 ..) instead of (1,1,1,1) if active or (0,0,0,0) if not.

How should I tackle this simple issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I've got you, not sure it does what you need. :)

```
Option Explicit

Public intReturnToHold As Double

Sub call_function()
    Debug.Print Alt(2, intReturnToHold)
End Sub
Function Alt(Soc1 As Double, Optional ByRef intHoldAlt)

Static D As Integer

Alt = intReturnToHold

If Soc1 >= 40 Then
    Alt = 0
ElseIf Soc1 <= 30 Then
    Alt = 1
End If

intHoldAlt = Alt

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Nathan for your answer. Altough I don't really understand your code I believe I get the idea of it but it did not work.

I have tried my previous idea again and for some reason it worked this time, here is the code;

```
Function Alt(Soc1 As Double)
Static D As Integer

If Soc1 >= 40 Then
    D = 0
ElseIf Soc1 <= 30 Then
    D = 1
End If
Alt = D
```

End Function

I have previously tired the EXACT same code and the results were as I said in my question "alternating" between 1 and 0 (when active) but now are constant 1 (when active).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but if you want a function to compute just once and then retain its value, you could do something like this:

```
Function Alt(Soc1 As Double) As Long
    Static D As Long
    Static Called As Boolean

    If Called Then
        Alt = D
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Soc1 >= 40 Then
        D = 0
    ElseIf Soc1 <= 30 Then
        D = 1
    End If

    Called = True
    Alt = D

End Function
```

On the other hand, if your goal is to have a function which, once it takes on the value 1 never resets to 0, something like this would work:

```
Function Alt(Soc1 As Double) As Long
    Static D As Long

    If D = 1 Then
        Alt = D
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Soc1 >= 40 Then
        D = 0
    ElseIf Soc1 <= 30 Then
        D = 1
    End If

    Alt = D

End Function
```